# как увести все кнопки в 1 сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу бота и возник вопрос как сделать так чтобы по нажатию любой из кнопок меня перекидывало в одно сообщение чтобы не расписывать его так. Если кто знает как изменить цвет этим кнопкам?

```
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'CV':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Development (Frontend, backend, full-stack, mobile, web, gamedev)',callback_data='Development')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Testing ',callback_data='Testing')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('DevOps/Admin',callback_data='DevOps')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Data Science ',callback_data='Data Science')
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('TOP Management (CTO, CIO, Director) ',callback_data='TOP')
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Support, Helpdesk',callback_data='Support')
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('PR, marketing, advertising',callback_data='PR')
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Project/Product manager,HR',callback_data='Project')
                item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Design',callback_data='Design')



                markup.add(item1)
                markup.add(item2,item3,item4)
                markup.add(item5)
                markup.add(item6,item7,item9)
                markup.add(item8,item8)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "CV - Choose a specialization :", reply_markup=markup)

            elif call.data == 'Vacancy':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('less then $1000', callback_data='less')

                markup.add(item1)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Your budget($):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="What would you like to create")
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['Development','Testing','DevOps','Data Science','TOP','Support','PR','Project','Design'])
def callback(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'Development':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior',callback_data='Junior')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle',callback_data='Middle')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior',callback_data='Senior')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead',callback_data='Teamlead')
                
                markup.add(item1,item2)
                markup.add(item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Role (Level):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="CV - Choose a specialization")

            if call.data == 'Testing':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior',callback_data='Junior')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle',callback_data='Middle')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior',callback_data='Senior')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead',callback_data='Teamlead')
                
                markup.add(item1,item2)
                markup.add(item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Role (Level):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="CV - Choose a specialization")

            if call.data == 'DevOps':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior',callback_data='Junior')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle',callback_data='Middle')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior',callback_data='Senior')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead',callback_data='Teamlead')
                
                markup.add(item1,item2)
                markup.add(item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Role (Level):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="CV - Choose a specialization")

            if call.data == 'Data Science':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior',callback_data='Junior')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle',callback_data='Middle')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior',callback_data='Senior')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead',callback_data='Teamlead')
                
                markup.add(item1,item2)
                markup.add(item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Role (Level):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="CV - Choose a specialization")

            if call.data == 'TOP':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior',callback_data='Junior')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle',callback_data='Middle')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior',callback_data='Senior')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead',callback_data='Teamlead')
                
                markup.add(item1,item2)
                markup.add(item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Role (Level):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="CV - Choose a specialization")

            if call.data == 'Support':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior',callback_data='Junior')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle',callback_data='Middle')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior',callback_data='Senior')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead',callback_data='Teamlead')
                
                markup.add(item1,item2)
                markup.add(item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Role (Level):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="CV - Choose a specialization")
            
            if call.data == 'PR':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior',callback_data='Junior')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle',callback_data='Middle')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior',callback_data='Senior')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead',callback_data='Teamlead')
                
                markup.add(item1,item2)
                markup.add(item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Role (Level):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="CV - Choose a specialization")

            if call.data == 'Project':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior',callback_data='Junior')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle',callback_data='Middle')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior',callback_data='Senior')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead',callback_data='Teamlead')
                
                markup.add(item1,item2)
                markup.add(item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Role (Level):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="CV - Choose a specialization")

            if call.data == 'Design':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior',callback_data='Junior')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle',callback_data='Middle')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior',callback_data='Senior')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead',callback_data='Teamlead')
                
                markup.add(item1,item2)
                markup.add(item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Role (Level):", reply_markup=markup)
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="CV - Choose a specialization")


    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Comment: Какое сообщения куда Вам нужно увести?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы на нажатие любой кнопки выводилось одно сообщение чтобы не расписывать каждой кнопке еще по 4-10 кнопок а потом и для них еще 5 кнопок . \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная проблема в том, что у Вас много ненужного и повторяющегося кода, который лучше вывести в отдельные функции, например.

Вы можете передать в функцию edit_text клавиатуру, и Вам не нужно по новой её отправлять.

Вот, оптимизировал Ваш код и все изменения будут по нажатию на кнопку будут происходить в одном сообщении, вместо отправки каждый раз нового.

От себя советую посмотреть и понять, что изменено, чтобы в следующий раз сэкономить лишние строки.

```py
def get_positions_keyboard() -> types.InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
        'Development (Frontend, backend, full-stack, mobile, web, gamedev)',
        callback_data='Development')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Testing ', callback_data='Position:Testing')
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('DevOps/Admin', callback_data='Position:DevOps')
    item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Data Science ', callback_data='Position:Data Science')
    item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('TOP Management (CTO, CIO, Director) ',
                                       callback_data='Position:TOP')
    item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Support, Helpdesk', callback_data='Position:Support')
    item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('PR, marketing, advertising',
                                       callback_data='Position:PR')
    item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Project/Product manager,HR',
                                       callback_data='Position:Project')
    item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Design', callback_data='Position:Design')

    return markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9)


def get_vacancies_keyboard() -> types.InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    return markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('less then $1000', callback_data='less'))


def get_levels_keyboard() -> types.InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)

    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Junior', callback_data='Junior')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Middle', callback_data='Middle')
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Senior', callback_data='Senior')
    item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Teamlead', callback_data='Teamlead')

    return markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'CV')
def cv_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = get_positions_keyboard()

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "CV - Choose a specialization :", reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'Vacancy')
def vacancy_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = get_vacancies_keyboard()
    text = "What would you like to create\n" \
           "Your budget($):"
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                          message_id=call.message.message_id,
                          text="What would you like to create")


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith('Position:'))
def position_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    position_data = call.data.split(':')[0]  # Development, Testing, DevOps, etc.
    text = "CV - Choose a specialization\n" \
           "Role (Level):"
    keyboard = get_levels_keyboard()
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                          message_id=call.message.message_id,
                          text=text)
```